# Android TextView setText results in empty text

Tags: android, textview, settext

I try to set the text of a TextView programmatically within a Fragment.
The code for the classes is as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data)
    {
       this.setFileName();
    }

    protected abstract void setFileName();
}

public class ImplementingFragment extends AbstractFragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View fragment = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setFileName()
    {
        String fileName = "Test.txt";

        TextView textView = ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.text_file_name));
        textView.setText(fileName);
    }
}
```

The Layout is as follows:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_pdf_filename_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_pdf_filename"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_pdf_file_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The weird thing is: within one Fragment it works, in another it does not (same parent Activity). Another fact is that after I set the text, I get it via textView.getText(). If I try to get the text in later code, I just get an empty string.

Additionally, if I debug the code, I see the text a view milliseconds, before it disappears.

Does anyone has an solution how to fix that behaviour?

Comment: what is `fileName`? Log the value of fileName before settign to textview and chekc yourself

Comment: @Raghunandan: the value of fileName is a string. It is not empty (I check that).

Comment: fileName is not empty then textView must be null leading to `NullPointerExcpetion`. Note:  setText can take null

Comment: @Raghunandan: The textView is also not NULL. No Exception occurs. The text is displayed for about a half a second, then disappears.

Comment: your code seems alright as of now. However you will need to post more code without which we will be only guessing. setText will do its job. it might be where you have this piece of code that matters

Comment: @Raghunandan: I added some more code

Answer (score -1):

Inside fragment use:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
            false);

    TextView textView = ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(
            R.id.text_file_name));
    textView.setText(fileName);

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: The Fragment is inflated in the right way. I get the TextView insight my method. Another View with same parent does work.

Comment: @der_chirurg you  need to post more code. TO which layout the textview belongs to and the relevant fragment code. Its difficult to tell what hapenning right now

Comment: @der_chirurg by the way you can communicate from fragment to activity and set the text in activity itself using interface as a callback

Comment: @Raghunandan: Yes, I know, but I need it that way.

Comment: @der_chirurg the problem seems to be where you are calling `setFileName()`

Comment: @Raghunandan: I call it from the abstract class. Please see my changed code.